# What's the probability of differences among n independent uniform distribution variables?

Tags: probability-distributions

Given n independent random variables $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$, they have standard uniform distributions over [0,1]. Then what's the probability that there is at least one $|x_i-x_j| >= d$ for any different $i,j$ and $0<=d<=1$?

The discrete form of this problem is as follow:

Given n independent random variables $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$, they have discrete uniform distributions over {0,1,2,...m}. Then what's the probability that there is at least one $|x_i-x_j| >= d$ for any different $i,j$ and the integer d satisfying $0<=d<=m$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite generally, if $P(x)$ is the probability density of $n$ independent random variables and $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}P(x')dx'$ is their cumulative distribution function, then the joint distribution of the smallest and largest variables $x_{\rm min}<x_{\rm max}$ is given by

$$P(x_{\rm min},x_{\rm max})=n(n-1)P(x_{\rm min})P(x_{\rm max})[F(x_{\rm max})-F(x_{\rm min})]^{n-2}.$$

Several ways to prove this result are given [here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198192)

You ask for the probability ${\cal P}(d)$ that the largest spacing exceeds $d$, which follows from

$${\cal P}(d)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx_{\rm min}\int_{x_{\rm min}+d}^{\infty}dx_{\rm max}\,P(x_{\rm min},x_{\rm max}).$$

For the uniform distribution $P(x)=1$ and $F(x)=x$ for $0<x<1$, so

$$P(x_{\rm min},x_{\rm max})=n(n-1)(x_{\rm max}-x_{\rm min})^{n-2},$$

for $0<x_{\rm min}<x_{\rm max}<1$, and

$${\cal P}(d)=\int_{0}^{1-d}dx_{\rm min}\int_{x_{\rm min}+d}^{1}dx_{\rm max}\,n(n-1)(x_{\rm max}-x_{\rm min})^{n-2}=1-n d^{n-1}+(n-1) d^{n}.$$

Two limits as a check: ${\cal P}(0)=1$, ${\cal P}(1)=0$ (assuming $n\geq 2$).

Comment: It seems you are finding the probability that $x_{max}-x_{min}\ge d$, which is not quite what the OP asked about.

Comment: did I misread the question? --- the probability that there is at least one spacing greater than $d$, isn't that the same as the probability that the largest spacing is greater than $d$?

Comment: Oups - sorry - my bad - thought he was asking about spacings between consecutive numbers in the linear order.

Comment: @Carlo I agree with your formulation that the probability sought is P(sample range > d). However, I get a different result.

Comment: @wolfies, I've corrected the error in the final integral, thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 4):

Let $X$ ~ Uniform(0,1) with pdf $f(x)$:

[image]

The joint pdf of the 1st and $n$th order statistics is, say, $g(x_\left(1\right), x_\left(n\right))$:

[image]

where I am using the `OrderStat` function from the `mathStatica` package for *Mathematica* to automate the nitty gritties for me (I am one of the authors of the former).

... and with domain of support:

[image]

We seek $P(X_\left(n\right)- X_\left(1\right) > d)$:

[image]

All done.

Comment: corrected, thanks for spotting my error.